# AVAudioSession disable Background Audio at runtime

Tags: ios

I am using the iOS background capabilities

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

I now want my users to be able to change this value at runtime. Is it possible to change this value at runtime or do i need to add logic to stop my audio in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method?

Comment: Add logic to stop it, you can't edit any of the files in your app bundle at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings you are describing are left aside your app and cannot be changed at runtime.
The correct way is to add logic yourself as you describe.